# How do I get the giomm-2.4 package?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gtk, gtkmm

I am trying to build a GTK application (c++) using NetBeans. After including the gtkmm.h file I had to use the pkg-config tool to determine what it's dependencies where. I then added them to the included folders. Netbean complains that it cannot find 'giomm-2.4'. This package does not exist in /usr/lib and I cannot seem to find this package in Synaptic.

Can someone tell me where to find it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this package: `libglibmm-2.4-dev`.

Comment: On MSYS2 it's `mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-glibmm`